# Thudding when slowing to brake

Tags: brakes, troubleshooting

2014 Jeep Compass Limited. Had brake pads, rotors, and calipers replaced ~6 months ago @dealer (had no issues, but @oil change appt dealer recommended). Have driven the car maybe 1,000 miles in 6 months (weekend vehicle). 2 weeks ago started to notice a rhythmic thud or thump noise when slowing to stop. Doesn't happen @high speeds and braking, just when about to stop the car. Front drivers side is where noise is coming from. The faster I go, the more frequent the noise and as I slow to stop, the noise is less frequent-happens at a certain point in rotation of tires seems like. Took it to garage for a quick look and they said everything looks fine. Diagnostics showed nothing. Any ideas other than paying to take everything apart?

Comment: Could be rotor moving or play in driveshaft joint.

Comment: I have had this symptom on several cars, replaced the brake pads and it went away. Only thing I could figure is cheap pads were the cause.